# Alternative to basic for loop to improve performance

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop checking for the presence of a condition in three columns. I would like to find a way to perform this more efficiently, as I'm actually running something similar to this in a very large database and the loop takes hours.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Binary1 = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0),
  Binary2 = c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0),
  Binary3 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1))

for(j in 1:nrow(df)) {df$CompoundSignal[j] <- ifelse (  df$Binary1[j] == 1 
                                                      & df$Binary2[j] == 1
                                                      & df$Binary3[j] == 1
                                                      , 1, 0)}
```

Comment: Just use `rowSums` as in `as.integer(rowSums(df[1:3]) == 3)`. You could also use `pmin(df$Binary1, df$Binary2, df$Binary3)` though you have to type the columns manually for this approach. And btw, `ifelse` is vectorized so you don't need a loop in your approach.

Comment: Thanks for help! You are right. There is not even need for a loop here. Want to put that as an answer rather than comment so I may mark the question as answered?

Comment: or even `apply(df, 1, function(x) as.numeric(all(x==1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different approaches without loops. Here are some of them:

```
as.integer(rowSums(df) == 3)
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

or

```
pmin(df$Binary1, df$Binary2, df$Binary3) 
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

or

```
as.integer(df$Binary1 & df$Binary2 & df$Binary3)
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

And btw, `ifelse` is vectorized so you don't need a loop in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
df$CompoundSignal = as.integer(df$Binary1==1 & df$Binary2==1 & df$Binary3==1)
```